# Column family ID mismatch (found 52ac10b0-6e1b-11e7-82d3-c39cc53c1347; expected 42e51050-6e1b-11e7-82d3-c39cc53c1347)

Tags: scala, cassandra, akka-stream, lagom

am running the Lagom online-auction-java and  am  having the  error , when  running below when i  execute  sbt  clean  runAll

```
    ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-13] 2017-07-21 16:52:45,704 ErrorMessage.java:384 - Unexpected exception during request
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch (found 52ac10b0-6e1b-11e7-82d3-c39cc53c1347; expected 42e51050-6e1b-11e7-82d3-c39cc53c1347)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:401) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager.announce(MigrationManager.java:529) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager.announceNewColumnFamily(MigrationManager.java:356) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager.announceNewColumnFamily(MigrationManager.java:341) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager.announceNewColumnFamily(MigrationManager.java:321) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.CreateTableStatement.announceMigration(CreateTableStatement.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SchemaAlteringStatement.execute(SchemaAlteringStatement.java:93) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:217) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:248) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:233) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.QueryMessage.execute(QueryMessage.java:116) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:517) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:410) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35) [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:162) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error happens when there was a schema change, which didn't get propagated to all the nodes in Cassandra.

Run the command

> nodetool describecluster

The output should contain a section called

> Schema versions:
>           65e78f0e-e81e-30d8-a631-a65dff93bf82: [127.0.0.1]

In case of this schema disagreement, there will be more than one schema version each associated with a separate set of nodes. Restart the Cassandra nodes which are in disagreement (showing different schema versions) one by one until everyone agrees to a specific schema version.

Comment: am just using  one node and the error  still  persists

Comment: Did you try restarting that single node?

Comment: thanks  and  restarting several  times  did  solve it and  i documented it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353421/column-family-id-mismatch-found-cebcc380-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799-expected