# Column family ID mismatch (found cebcc380-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799; expected c05d6970-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799)

Tags: cassandra, polymorphic-associations, akka-persistence, lagom

How can  i resolve this error
 Column family ID mismatch (found cebcc380-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799; expected c05d6970-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799)

```
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch (found cebcc380-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799; expected c05d6970-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:397) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Column family ID mismatch (found cebcc380-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799; expected c05d6970-72d4-11e7-9a6b-bd620b945799)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.validateCompatibility(CFMetaData.java:808) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.apply(CFMetaData.java:770) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.updateTable(Schema.java:621) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.updateKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:1430) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchema(SchemaKeyspace.java:1386) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.mergeSchemaAndAnnounceVersion(SchemaKeyspace.java:1336) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager$1.runMayThrow(MigrationManager.java:547) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.0.jar:3.11.0]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column family ID mismatch (found 52ac10b0-6e1b-11e7-82d3-c39cc53c1347; expected 42e51050-6e1b-11e7-82d3-c39cc53c1347)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239594/column-family-id-mismatch-found-52ac10b0-6e1b-11e7-82d3-c39cc53c1347-expected)

Answer (score 3):

Am using  Apache-cassandra-3.11.0  installed in  Fedora 25  and the  error  above  keeps repeating itself , after many google  searches ,  i did decided to  tackle it , i configured ntp  to  help Synchronizing Clocks in the  cassandra cluster  and  then  after the  error appeared on another terminal tab  i did
execute `./bin/nodetool drain` for cassandra to stop accepting requests   and  then  i did  `./bin/nodetool stopdaemon`  to gracefully  kill  cassandra and  then  restarted  the cassandra  server and then started  the  lagom project again  and after doing this process  twice  the error  dissappeared and my application was able to  load successfully  with both cassandra and it  working in harmony .

Comment: It helped me to make sure my cassandra is properly closed, then started and above issue disappeared.